# Datatable footer summary in label out of the footer asp.net core 2.2 using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, datatable

I try to get datatable footer sum in a Label out of th footer in HTML using javascript

here is the code

```
        <table id="tbldata" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Investigation.</th>
                    <th>Rs.</th>
                    <th style="width:5%">Delete.</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach (investigationonly p in Model.investigationonly)
            {
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @p.investigation
                        </td>
                        <td class="countable">
                            @p.price
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:5%">
                            Delete
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            }
            <tfoot>
                <tr>

                    <th colspan="3" style="text-align:right">Total:<label id="lbltotal"></label></th>

                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table><label id="txttotalpayble"></label>
```

Here is a screenshot of table working in footer successfully
[image]

as you can see its showing total sum in the footer but I try to show in label also

here is the javascript function

```
<script>
var cls = document.getElementById("tbldata").getElementsByTagName("td");
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
    if (cls[i].className == "countable") {
        sum += isNaN(cls[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(cls[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
document.getElementById("lbltotal").innerHTML = sum;
document.getElementById("txttotalpayble").innerHTML = sum;
```

Comment: This should work fine. Could you post the actual HTML being rendered with some test data instead of the CSHTML? Your problem has to do with the HTML/JS interaction, so it would be more helpful to us to have the HTML vs. the CSHTML

Comment: What's the browser you used ? Try to use the DevTools to check the source of generated HTML and whether there is error and make the breakpoint at the js to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem my self problem is simple and the solution is very simple.

I just change Inner.html to value

```
<script>
var cls = document.getElementById("tbldata").getElementsByTagName("td");
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
    if (cls[i].className == "countable") {
        sum += isNaN(cls[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(cls[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
document.getElementById("lbltotal").innerHTML = sum;
document.getElementById("txttotalpayble").value = sum;
```

Here are code and its working fine as I expected.